# executing two events consecutively in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I write a Form in c# with some controls. there is an event on one of the controls which is called when we leaved. in some situations when the value in the box is not valid, it throw a exception (if a bool variable is true). Now the problem is that when the focus is on this control and I want to close the form, the event for leaving this control is called and an exception has thrown which is catch in catch statement and no exception will be thrown but after that onclose event is will not call and I can't close the form. what should I do?

```
    private void SetSelectedDateTime(CancelEventArgs e, bool raiseException)
    {
        try
        {
            var newval = UpdateDateTime();
            var rawText = Text.Replace("/", "").Replace(":", "").Replace("_", "").Replace(" ", "");
            if ((Text.Contains(PromptChar) && rawText != string.Empty) || (!Text.Contains(PromptChar) && newval == null))
            {
                throw new SgException(ControlMessages.InvalidDate);
            }
            else
            {
                selectedDateTime = AdjustDateTime(selectedDateTime);
                if (newval != selectedDateTime)
                {
                    selectedDateTime = newval;
                    UpdateText(newval);
                    OnSelectedDateTimeChanged();
                    EndEditBindings();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            if (raiseException)
            {
                this.Focus();
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please, provide code which you have to make question clear

Comment: Provide only code related to this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should remove this line

```
  throw;
```

Comment: in some situation I want to throw exception!

Comment: but this throw exception causes that you can't close form

Comment: when raiseexception is false I cant close the form too!

Comment: you should change e.cancel to false